# Prepared Statement Insert With Select two tables

Tags: mysql

[image]I am using a prepared statement to insert data from **table 1** into **table 2** (a copy of **table 1**)

Only difference is **table 2** has a `DateTime` column. I am trying to insert the data from **table 1** into **table 2**. But how can I add the datetime(current time and date)?

I am a little suck on how to add this into my prepared statement.

```
DECLARE sqlquery text;
SET sqlquery = CONCAT('insert into partial_log select inaid, `PartNo`,`LineCode`,`EPartsPartNo`,`Surcharge`,`Price`,`CustomerDescription`,`ShortCode`,`PlusCode`,`LiveDate`,`CustomerPartNo`,`Alt1LineCode`,`Alt1PartNo`,`Alt1EPartsPartNo`,`Alt2LineCode`,`Alt2PartNo`,`Alt2EPartsPartNo`,`Alt3LineCode`,`Alt3PartNo`,`Alt3EPartsPartNo`,`Alt4LineCode`,`Alt4PartNo`,`Alt4EPartsPartNo`,`Alt5LineCode`,`Alt5PartNo`,`Alt5EPartsPartNo`,`Alt6LineCode`,`Alt6PartNo`,`Alt6EPartsPartNo`,`Alt7LineCode`,`Alt7PartNo`,`Alt7EPartsPartNo`,`Alt8LineCode`,`Alt8PartNo`,`Alt8EPartsPartNo`,`Alt9LineCode`,`Alt9PartNo`,`Alt9EPartsPartNo`,`Alt10LineCode`,`Alt10PartNo`,`Alt10EPartsPartNo`,',NOW(),',FROM itable order by `LineCode`,`PartNo`;');
set sqlquery=REPLACE(sqlquery,'inaid',inaid);
set sqlquery=REPLACE(sqlquery,'itable',itable);

SET @stat = sqlquery;
PREPARE stmt from @stat;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I have tried to add Now() by using concat but this does not work and throws invalid syntax error.
**#42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:00:06,FROM Ats order by `LineCode`,`PartNo`' at line 1**

**UPDATE:**
Do not need CONCAT to add NOW() into the statement.

```
DECLARE sqlquery text;
SET sqlquery = 'insert into partial_log select inaid, `PartNo`,`LineCode`,`EPartsPartNo`,`Surcharge`,`Price`,`CustomerDescription`,`ShortCode`,`PlusCode`,`LiveDate`,`CustomerPartNo`,`Alt1LineCode`,`Alt1PartNo`,`Alt1EPartsPartNo`,`Alt2LineCode`,`Alt2PartNo`,`Alt2EPartsPartNo`,`Alt3LineCode`,`Alt3PartNo`,`Alt3EPartsPartNo`,`Alt4LineCode`,`Alt4PartNo`,`Alt4EPartsPartNo`,`Alt5LineCode`,`Alt5PartNo`,`Alt5EPartsPartNo`,`Alt6LineCode`,`Alt6PartNo`,`Alt6EPartsPartNo`,`Alt7LineCode`,`Alt7PartNo`,`Alt7EPartsPartNo`,`Alt8LineCode`,`Alt8PartNo`,`Alt8EPartsPartNo`,`Alt9LineCode`,`Alt9PartNo`,`Alt9EPartsPartNo`,`Alt10LineCode`,`Alt10PartNo`,`Alt10EPartsPartNo`, NOW() FROM itable order by `LineCode`,`PartNo`;';
set sqlquery=REPLACE(sqlquery,'inaid',inaid);
set sqlquery=REPLACE(sqlquery,'itable',itable);

SET @stat = sqlquery;
PREPARE stmt from @stat;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: The CONCAT seems totally unnecessary and that is causing you the problem with incorrect syntax

Comment: I only used CONCAT here to ADD NOW(), other than that, I agree it would be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CONCAT is totally unnecessary, and just adding to your confusion.

Your query can be written like this

```
SET sqlquery = 'insert into partial_log 
                   select   inaid, `PartNo`,`LineCode`,
                            `EPartsPartNo`,`Surcharge`,`Price`,
                            `CustomerDescription`,`ShortCode`,`PlusCode`,
                            `LiveDate`,`CustomerPartNo`,`Alt1LineCode`,
                            `Alt1PartNo`,`Alt1EPartsPartNo`,`Alt2LineCode`,
                            `Alt2PartNo`,`Alt2EPartsPartNo`,`Alt3LineCode`,
                            `Alt3PartNo`,`Alt3EPartsPartNo`,`Alt4LineCode`,
                            `Alt4PartNo`,`Alt4EPartsPartNo`,`Alt5LineCode`,
                            `Alt5PartNo`,`Alt5EPartsPartNo`,`Alt6LineCode`,
                            `Alt6PartNo`,`Alt6EPartsPartNo`,`Alt7LineCode`,
                            `Alt7PartNo`,`Alt7EPartsPartNo`,`Alt8LineCode`,
                            `Alt8PartNo`,`Alt8EPartsPartNo`,`Alt9LineCode`,
                            `Alt9PartNo`,`Alt9EPartsPartNo`,`Alt10LineCode`,
                            `Alt10PartNo`,`Alt10EPartsPartNo`, NOW() 
                  FROM itable order by `LineCode`,`PartNo`;');
```

In fact as long as the columns are all in the same order in both the `partial_log` and `itable` tabless with only the addition of the new column `datetime` at the end of `partial_log` you could write the query like this

```
SET sqlquery = 'insert into partial_log 
                      SELECT  a.*, NOW() 
                      FROM itable a 
                      ORDER BY a.LineCode,a.PartNo
```

Comment: does this not count NOW() as a column?

Comment: It will add the result of a `NOW()` i.e. `2016-01-04 10:11:12` to each row so the selected rows will all posses the extra DateTime column you wanted placed in your `partial_log` table

Comment: I have just tried this, and get this #21S01Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Ok so now check that `partial_log` is an exact copy of `itable` with just the extra column at the end containing the new DateTime. With all the columns in the same order as your select

Comment: I have take a screen shot and update the question highlighting the difference.

Comment: See additional suggestion for simplifying the query even further